# Detect Keep-Alive timeout in TDSTCPServerTransport.OnDisconnect event

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy, keep-alive, datasnap

In DataSnap, is it possible to detect if a TCP connection was closed because a Keep-Alive timout was reached or just a graceful disconnect from the client?

```
procedure TsrvService.DSTCPServerTransport1Connect(
  Event: TDSTCPConnectEventObject);
begin
  Writeln('Connect from ', Event.Channel.ChannelInfo.ClientInfo.IpAddress);
  Event.Channel.EnableKeepAlive(10000, 100);
end;

procedure TsrvService.DSTCPServerTransport1Disconnect(
  Event: TDSTCPDisconnectEventObject);
begin
  Writeln('Disconnect : ', TIdTcpConnection(Event.Connection).Socket.Binding.PeerIP);
  // Keep-Alive Timeout or any other reason for disconnect???
  // Log('Keep-Alive Timeout for host...');
end;
```

Comment: DataSnap does not expose timeout info, though you might check if `Event.Channel.ConnectionLost` is meaningful inside the `OnDisconnect` event. At least if you used Indy directly, you can catch timeout exceptions directly, but you can't do that with DataSnap.

Comment: TDSTCPDisconnectEventObject (Event) has no member "Channel". This is only available in TDSTCPConnectEventObject.

Comment: Then you are SOL, sorry.